# In GLM do we try to model E(T(y)) or E(y)?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, intuition, exponential-family, link-function

I'm trying to follow Andrew NG [cs course on supervised learning](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf). He defines the exponential family as:
$$ 
p(y;\eta) = b(y)exp(\eta T(y) -a(\eta))
$$
and then continues to say that "our goal is to predict the expected value of $T(y)$ given $x$", and that "the `canonical response function` is $g(\eta) = E(T(y);\eta)$"

Why is that? why do we try to predict the mean of some $T(y)$ we don't care anything about instead of trying to predict $E(y)$?

In [a Canadian stat course](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~raltman/stat402/402L7.pdf), I found another definition of the exponential family:

$$ f_{Y}(y;\theta)=exp(yb(\theta) + c(\theta) + d(y)) $$ and there they clearly say: "In a GLM, the relationship between a function of $E[Y]$ and the parameters is linear."

So who's right here? what are we trying to model and what's the intuition behind it? is $T(y)$ an important concept to understand - and if so what's the intuition behind it as well?

Answer (score 2):

Your first definition is the general definition of an exponential family, the same as in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). Using this for iid sampling $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ from a normal distribution $(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we get
$$
   T(x_1, \dotsc,x_n)=(\sum x_i^2, n\bar{x})
$$
that is, the sufficient statistics. And yes, this is an important general concept!  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic).

This is too general to use with generalized linear models (glm's) when the following definition is used (corresponding to your second definition, but augmented)
$$
   f(y_i; \theta_i, \phi)= \exp[A_i \{y_i \theta_i -\gamma(\theta_i)\}/\phi + \tau(y_i, \phi/A_i)]
$$ (cited here from Venables & Ripley MASS, 4th edition).  For the normal distribution above we get $\phi=\sigma^2$, $\theta=\mu, \gamma(\theta)=\theta^2/2$.

In this restricted formulation, the glm general theory is only about modeling the observable $Y_i$ itself, and the canonical parameter $\theta=\mu$ (in this case). How to estimate the scale parameter $\phi$ is outside this general framework, and must be treated on its own in each special case.